# In Apache Ant, is there a way to take an argument from an ant command and use that as a key for a property file?

Tags: xml, apache, ant, properties-file

Say we have an parameter being passed into an ant command like so:

```
ant -Dparameter="potato" myAntCommand
```

Normally, we'd obtain that that parameter in our build.xml like so:

```
<target name="myAntCommand">
    <echo message="${parameter}"/>
</target>
```

Is it possible through ant to use that same parameter to obtain a value from a properties file ?

For example, if we had a properties file that held the following values:

```
potato="HelloWorld"
strawberry="GoodbyeWorld"
```

Is there any way I could have the previous code pass in "potato" as a parameter and have "HelloWorld" as an output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a way, but you will have to download a JAR and add it to your Ant installation.

You will need [Antlibs Props](http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/props/index.html) which is listed as one of the [Apache Ant Libraries](http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/proper.html), but it's not available for download at the site (only the GIT repository is listed). As you can see documented in that last page, you can use the `nested` delegate to allow nested property expansion.

The JAR is `ant-props-1.0Alpha.jar`. I have no idea why it's no longer available. Searching for it, I found it avaliable at [this link](http://ftp.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadantprops10Alphajar.htm) which is not an official download site, but it might be useful for now.

You just need to drop the JAR into your `$ANT_HOME/lib` directory to be able to use it in any project.

In your `build.xml` you have to set up the namespaces and typedefs for the extension. Add this somewhere inside your `<project>`:

```
<typedef uri="antlib:org.apache.ant.props"
         resource="org/apache/ant/props/antlib.xml"
         classpath="ant-props-1.0Alpha.jar"/>
```

And then you can use turn the feature on like this:

```
<propertyhelper xmlns:props="antlib:org.apache.ant.props">
    <props:nested />
</propertyhelper>
```

Now you can use the `${${property}}` syntax to resolve a property that resolves to another.

Here is a full example. I declared the properties in the file, but it would work the same with properties in a *Properties file* or using `-D` at the command line:

```
<project default="command">
    <typedef uri="antlib:org.apache.ant.props"
             resource="org/apache/ant/props/antlib.xml"
             classpath="ant-props-1.0Alpha.jar"/>

    <propertyhelper xmlns:props="antlib:org.apache.ant.props">
       <props:nested />
    </propertyhelper>

    <property name="potato" value="HelloWorld"/>
    <property name="parameter" value="potato"/>

    <target name="command">
        <echo message="${${parameter}}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

When you run:

```
ant
```

it prints:

```
command:
     [echo] HelloWorld
```